# Loading multiple files from S3 to Redshift, query completing no data in tables

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a script firing from lambda that executes the following query:

```
 COPY test.error_log__c
        FROM 's3://sfdc-etl-jp-test/sfdc_etl/json/error_log__c_json/2019/03/23/'
        iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/LambdaFullAccessRole'
        TRUNCATECOLUMNS
        JSON 'auto'
```

However, the tables are empty even though the query completes successfully.  There are anywhere between 1 and 100 files in these paths.  I am guessing that the copy command isn't smart enough to know what the file name is and that is why this isn't working.  Am I right?  if so how do I tell it to load multiple files?

Here is the code being executed in case this isn't a query issue:

```
create_engine('postgres://{}:{}@{}/ibdrs'.format(igersUser, igersPwd, igersHost), encoding="utf-8")

 loadQuery = '''
        COPY {}.{}
        FROM '{}{}/{}'
        iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/LambdaFullAccessRole' 
        TRUNCATECOLUMNS
        JSON 'auto'
        EMPTYASNULL
        TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
        DATEFORMAT 'auto'
        COMPUPDATE OFF
        STATUPDATE ON
    '''.format(igersSchema, nextObj, s3Destination, s3Path.format(nextObj), dated_path)

with igers.connect() as conn:
        try :
            conn.execute(drop_table)
            print('completed drop table')
            conn.execute(ddl_str)
            print('completed create table')
            conn.execute(loadQuery).execution_options(autocommit=True)
            print('completed load query')
            for row in range(len(groupPerms)) :
                perms_statement = grantPerms.format(groupPerms['namespace'].iloc[row],groupPerms['item'].iloc[row],groupPerms['groname'].iloc[row])
                conn.execute(perms_statement)
            print('completed grant group permissions')
            conn.close()
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e :
            print(e)
```

Note: Yes I know there are other queries, they are not shown as they are executing.  Drop table, recreate table, re-apply permissions are all working and verified working.  It is just the copy from S3 that is doing nothing.

Comment: executing this directly on the redshift via navicat results in 132 records being added.  why would this not work via EC2 / Lambda in a script with that role associated with them

Comment: I looked at the Redshift logs and there appears to be no difference between the queries the Redshift is seeing from manual execution via navicat and scripted execution via lambda.  What else should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is .... apparently order matters to sqlalchemy:

```
create_engine('postgres://{}:{}@{}/ibdrs'.format(igersUser, igersPwd, igersHost), encoding="utf-8")

 loadQuery = '''
        COPY {}.{}
        FROM '{}{}/{}'
        iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/LambdaFullAccessRole' 
        TRUNCATECOLUMNS
        JSON 'auto'
        EMPTYASNULL
        TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
        DATEFORMAT 'auto'
        COMPUPDATE OFF
        STATUPDATE ON
    '''.format(igersSchema, nextObj, s3Destination, s3Path.format(nextObj), dated_path)

with igers.connect() as conn:
        try :
            conn.execute(drop_table)
            print('completed drop table')
            conn.execute(ddl_str)
            print('completed create table')
            conn.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute(loadQuery)
            print('completed load query')
            for row in range(len(groupPerms)) :
                perms_statement = grantPerms.format(groupPerms['namespace'].iloc[row],groupPerms['item'].iloc[row],groupPerms['groname'].iloc[row])
                conn.execute(perms_statement)
            print('completed grant group permissions')
            conn.close()
        except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e :
            print(e)
```

you'll notice the order change to the auto_commit.